# Autofix CSS/SCSS files with semicolons

Tags: css, prettier, stylelint, prettier-standard

I'm looking for a way to have my CSS and SCSS code automatically fill in missing semicolons at the end of lines when needed.

I've tried both Prettier and Stylelint and both seem to notice the error but without autofixing it on format.

Is there some setting or rule in .prettierrc or .stylelintrc that can autofix this?